# How to grab a sticky post in facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can grab posts of facebook page by using facebook graph API,but I don't know how to grab sticky post
Is it possible?
Thanks,

#
like this page 
https://www.facebook.com/pages/OB%E5%9A%B4%E9%81%B8/397486643273

there has a flag picture on the upper right corner top of the post

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2S9Q.png

Comment: What do you mean by "sticky post"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not currently possible to determine, via the Graph API, if a post on a page has been pinned. There thus currently no way to get pinned posts for a Page.

For reference, here's more info about pinned posts: https://www.facebook.com/help/235598533193464